# WeChat of android can not support getUserMedia with https.Why?

Tags: html, https, getusermedia, wechat

I need use getUserMedia and https in pages of WeChat.But WeChat of android can not support getUserMedia with https.followings are demos that I tested.Who can help me? Thanks.

demo1 : https://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php

demo2 : https://alexandre.alapetite.fr/doc-alex/html5-webcam/index.en.html

WeChat is a messagers in China.It can visit mobile pages.

Comment: "WeChat of android can not support getUserMedia with https" Can you provide more details ?

Comment: sorry。Please ignore this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to include in your website a "WeChat widget". Your website must use https because of getUserMedia and WeChat do not support https?

There is no solution except proxy the WeChat service through your https website, if your visitors trust you to give you their WeChat credentials.

You can ask WeChat to start support https, it will be a huge security improvement...